# Detect if it is past a certain hour (e.g. 3pm)

Tags: javascript, date

I can't work out the logic to detect if it is past a certain hour yet...

```
var now = new Date();
if(now.getHours() <= 15 && now.getMinutes() < 1) console.log("It's before 3pm");
```

Comment: 14:30 is before 15:00 so you can see that you do not want to add restriction to minutes. Just hours less than 15 should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh, was rather silly

```
var now = new Date();
if(now.getHours() >= 15) console.log('Past 3pm');
```